# Why am I not able to install JSON gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, rubygems, jekyll

1. I am getting Bundle Updated when I run `bundle update`
2. Json 1.8.6 is installed.
3. But when I run jekyll build, I get this error:

   WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
         listen (< 3.1, ~> 3.0)
   WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
   Please report a bug if this causes problems.
   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:40:in `block in setup': You have already activated json 2.0.2, but your Gemfile requires json 1.8.6. Prepending`bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)

Comment: As the warning suggest you can prepend `bundle exec` to your command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you have multiple versions of `json` installed and the wrong version is being used

> Prepending **`bundle exec`** to your command may solve this.

As the warning suggest you can add `bundle exec` before your command. This will make sure to use the Gem versions mentioned in your `Gemfile`.

```
bundle exec jekyll build
```

and

```
bundle exec jekyll serve
```

Comment: So, from now on, I can't use bundle serve? Always use exec? It works, though. Thanks.

Comment: bundle exec just ensure that the right version of gem will be used

Comment: @maximusdooku: alias j='bundle exec jekyll' - lets you "j serve". Much easier!